# Ubuntu Center Ratings and How to Submit Them

Tags: software-center

I would like to rate the DeVeDe package as its buggy and deserves a low rating, plus I can tell people what they have to do to make it work.  I tried running the command, software-center devede, but ratings or submitting ratings is not available.  I have software-center version 5.2.9 running on Ubuntu 12.04 on two different machines

My issue with DeVeDe is that it changes the imported movie size without updating the disk usage in the main window.  Disk usage seems to indicate the input files, not the files to be written.  Adding a video file to a title automatically changes the output size of the input even if you select don't do that.  You must manually change the output video and audio frequencies to match the input in order to not change them.  Selecting optimize to fit disk on the main window errors out.  Very frustrating to spend 3 hours creating a 9GB iso image when the DVD will only hold 4.7GB with no indication that this is what DeVeDe is doing.  Takes a long time and numerous tries to find these types of problems.  (Many Evenings).  Which is why I think the current rating of 4.3 is wrong and I'ld like to submit mine...

Now if I could figure out why the titles are invisible on the bluray player, and why the iso file will not play in VLC, I'll have a decent way to move my old 8mm tapes to dvd.

If we can not input ratings then I wouldn't trust them as I don't know where they came from.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't use ratings as a means for reporting bugs. You should [report a bug on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/devede), instead.

To answer the question of how to submit ratings for an app in Software Center, you simply need to go to that app in Software Center, and submit a review, and you must have the app installed, in order to submit a review. A log in window will pop up to log in to Ubuntu One, if you are not already logged in.